# mysql use next value in a sequence as default value for a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table having a column (say order) that needs it values to be in sequence (0,1,2,3...N,0,1,2,3...N,0...).
It will start with zero and the next value of that column (order) should be 1 and so on until it reaches max number N (say 5). then the next value should be zero again.

Comment: sequence based on what??

Comment: sequence like 1,2,3...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a program to add a new column just control the value in the way what you want to do. For example: insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3) values("","",0);insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3) values("","",1)...insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3) values("","",N),insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3) values("","",0),insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3) values("","",1)...  of course you need use "order by id" to make sure the table is order by the insertion order.